# how detect OS name and version of the URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my app I want to get a website address from the user and show to him the operating system of that website (i.e., what OS server is running on).  How can I do this?

best regard

Comment: you mean you want the Operating system of the server where the Website is hosted!

Comment: It's really not clear what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

check this [Link](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-methods.html) and [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_stack_fingerprinting) about the theory, nmap uses known signatures to detect the OS version, so if you can use their text-based database this may help you, alternativly you can run nmap in a hidden process and parse its fingerprint output to detect the remote OS.

Comment: Caveat: An `nmap` scan is often seen as hostile.

Comment: @todda.speot.is: your right, i wanted just to mention the option that remote OS detection exists and one way is using a textbased signatures database, i had no other intentions here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't 100%, you can be told roughly what web server it's using, so if it's IIS you can guess it's Windows but there's no hard and fast rules, I could make my Apache on Linux tell you it's IIS or a cat.

I think what you need it HttpWebResponse.Server - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.server.aspx

Comment: desc:
System.Net.WebRequest re = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com");
        System.Net.WebResponse rs = re.GetResponse();
        Response.Write(rs.Headers[0]);

how we can detect OS in response?

Answer (score -1):

Send an HTTP 1.0 or 1.1 query and you may receive a 'Server' heading in the reply. That's typically the best you can do.

Comment: in header ["server"] we can get web server but no OS !

Comment: It's hard to answer a question you don't understand. What do you think it means to ask what the OS of a web site is? A web site is a function, a result, it's not a computer. What the OS of McDonald's?

Comment: If the web site uses FreeBSD load balancers, a Linux web server front end, back end databases on Windows machines with storage on FreeNAS boxes, what is the "OS of the web site"?